# Точки разного размера в UIPageControl

Tags: swift, pagination, ios10

UIPageControl из коробки не позволяет сделать активную и неактивную точки разного размера. Какой самый простой/оптимальный способ это сделать? (только полностью Swift'овые решения)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовал пользовательский класс, отнаследованный от UIPageControl. В нем нужно указать две картинки, которые будут являться активной и неактивной "точкой" пейджинатора. В остальном - все тоже самое, как с обычным UIPageControl, в числе и в storyboard

```
import UIKit

class MELPageControl: UIPageControl {

    private let activeImage = UIImage(named: "paginatorDotGreen")!
    private let inactiveImage = UIImage(named: "paginatorDotGray")!

    // MARK: - @Overrides

    override var numberOfPages: Int {
        didSet {
            updateDots()
        }
    }

    override var currentPage: Int {
        didSet {
            updateDots()
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.clear
        currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.clear
        clipsToBounds = false
    }

    // MARK: - Private Methods

    private func updateDots() {
        var i = 0
        for view in self.subviews {
            if let imageView = imageForSubview(view) {
                if i == currentPage {
                    imageView.image = activeImage
                } else {
                    imageView.image = inactiveImage
                }
                i += 1
            } else {
                var dotImage = inactiveImage
                if i == currentPage {
                    dotImage = activeImage
                }

                view.clipsToBounds = false
                view.addSubview(UIImageView(image: dotImage))
                i += 1
            }
        }
    }

    private func imageForSubview(_ view: UIView) -> UIImageView? {
        var dot: UIImageView?

        if let dotImageView = view as? UIImageView {
            dot = dotImageView
        } else {
            for foundView in view.subviews {
                if let imageView = foundView as? UIImageView {
                    dot = imageView
                    break
                }
            }
        }

        return dot
    }
}
```

Если есть решение проще - поделитесь )

Answer (score 0):

Есть не плохая библиотека [FXPageControle](https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXPageControl). Единственное, она написана на Objective C, ее надо будет реализовать через Bridge. [Migration to Objective C](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/migrating_your_objective_c_code_to_swift).

Так же можно создать `UIView` с инициализатором количества pages в виде `UIButton` внутри. Создать для каждого page `#selector` и анимировать в зависимости от нажатий. (Это длительный процесс но более кастомный) [Building a Custom Page Control](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/building-a-custom-uipagecontrol-in-swift-3592af78a844).

Comment: к сожалению, библиотека на objective-c не вариант )

Comment: Почему ? Bridge у Apple реализован очень не плохо ))

Comment: не хочется тащить obj-c в чисто свифтовый проект

Answer (score 0):

Возможно Вас устроят следующие библиотеки (swift):

[ISPageControl](https://github.com/Interactive-Studio/ISPageControl)

[SCPageControl](https://github.com/myoungsc/SCPageControl)

[FlexiblePageControl](https://github.com/shima11/FlexiblePageControl)